# code igniter add back quote a query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

i have a problem with codeigniter query the query is the next.

This Is my method :

```
public function CargarProceso($idUsuario, $estatus)
    {

      $joinQuery = 'procesos_cotizaciones.proveedor =';
      $joinQuery .= (string) $idUsuario;
      $joinQuery .=  ' AND procesos_cotizaciones.estatus =';
      $joinQuery .= "\"".$estatus."\"";
      $joinQuery .= ' AND procesos_cotizaciones.proceso = planos_procesos.id';

      $this->db->select('procesos_cotizaciones.proveedor,procesos_cotizaciones.estatus, planos_procesos.proceso, planos_proyecto.nombre_archivo');
      $this->db->from('procesos_cotizaciones');
      $this->db->join('planos_procesos', $joinQuery, 'inner');
      $this->db->join('planos_proyecto','planos_procesos.plano = planos_proyecto.id','inner');
      $this->db->group_by('planos_proyecto.nombre_archivo', 'asc');

      $query = $this->db->get();
      //var_dump($query);
      return $query;
    }
```

the string in $joinQuery is:

```
"procesos_cotizaciones.proveedor =90004 AND procesos_cotizaciones.estatus ="ORDEN DE COMPRA" AND procesos_cotizaciones.proceso = planos_procesos.id"
```

but return a error database query because codeigniter add back quote in the query, and send to mysql.

```
SELECT `procesos_cotizaciones`.`proveedor`, `procesos_cotizaciones`.`estatus`, `planos_procesos`.`proceso`, `planos_proyecto`.`nombre_archivo` FROM `procesos_cotizaciones` INNER JOIN `planos_procesos` ON `procesos_cotizaciones`.`proveedor` =90004 AND `procesos_cotizaciones`.`estatus` ="ORDEN DE `COMPRA"` AND `procesos_cotizaciones`.`proceso` = `planos_procesos`.`id` INNER JOIN `planos_proyecto` ON `planos_procesos`.`plano` = `planos_proyecto`.`id` ORDER BY `planos_proyecto`.`nombre_archivo` ASC
```

the back quote is add on `Compra"`

Comment: What is `$estatus` and why is it being [injected](http://bobby-tables.com/) into the query without any escaping whatsoever?

Comment: sorry $estatus variable is a string parameter who receives the function for example 'cotizado' or 'EN NEGOCIACION'.

Comment: i edit the code, i hope to been more explicit

Comment: I get that. What I mean is it's extremely risky to just stuff that in a query. You should, at the absolute least, escape it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

`$this->db->join()` accepts an optional fourth parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names.

```
$this->db->select('procesos_cotizaciones.proveedor,procesos_cotizaciones.estatus, planos_procesos.proceso, planos_proyecto.nombre_archivo');
$this->db->from('procesos_cotizaciones');
$this->db->join('planos_procesos', $joinQuery, 'inner', FALSE);
$this->db->join('planos_proyecto','planos_procesos.plano = planos_proyecto.id','inner', FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('planos_proyecto.nombre_archivo', 'asc');

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::join